# to print each character of a word in c program

Tags: c, turbo-c

I am having a c program which print letter by letter of the word. I referred this program from this link
https://www.tutorialgateway.org/c-program-to-print-characters-in-a-string/. If I run this program in online c compiler this gives the exact result, but not working in turbo c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char str[100];
        
    printf("\n Please Enter any String  :  ");
    scanf("%s", str);
        
    for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        printf("The Character at %d Index Position = %c \n", i, str[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This program doesn't through any error, but I don't know why this program doesn't print the result.

Comment: " but not working in turbo ++"- what exactly happens?

Comment: neither creates an error nor the result, it runs but the resulting page get terminates automatically without printing the result

Comment: What is your input to the program? Did you try running your program under a debugger?

Comment: it should be Turbo C++ not Turbo ++. read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C%2B%2B

Comment: @manju Possibly the application terminates. If you add something like `getchar();` at the end of your program (before return statement), it might "hold" the screen for you so that you can see the output.

Comment: @P.P, you means getch();?, but I want to print this without clrscr() and getch()

Comment: Turbo C++ is a C++ compiler, not a C compiler, and it is obsolete.  Do not use it.  There are better alternatives.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Turbo C++ is quite interesting in this regard. It will treat a `.c` or `.cas` file as a C file or a `.cpp` or `.cxx` file as a C++ file and an `.obj` or `.lib` file as pass to the linker. I don't remember what it did with other extensions.

Comment: Try [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) instead of Turbo C or Turbo C++. For C code, use it as  `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `fgets(str, 100, stdin)` instead of `scanf()`. This is the normal way to read a line into a buffer. When I used `scanf()` I only got part of the output because it will stop reading a string at a space.

Answer (score 1):

IDK what is your output, but here is mine:

```
 Please Enter any String  :  Hell got loose
The Character at 0 Index Position = H 
The Character at 1 Index Position = e 
The Character at 2 Index Position = l 
The Character at 3 Index Position = l
```

This is normal, due to this:

> Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next pointer must be a pointer to character array that is long enough to hold the input sequence and the terminating null character ('\0'), which is added automatically. The input string stops at white space or at the maximum field width, whichever occurs first.

this is taken from `scanf`.

EDIT:
Just for the fun, you can do this using `scanf`

```
scanf("%[^\n]",str);
```

this will replace `\n` newline with '\0'.

NOTE: @Joshua's answer is safer, if you want to know why just google why I shouldn't use `scanf()`

Comment: if I user strlen() this works properly, but using this condition str[i] != '\0' in for loop makes this issue

Comment: @manju I am not sure, but turbo C++ has its "problems", plus it was more focused on C++ by itself, so I do not know how does it treat `scanf()`.

Comment: @0x476f72616e: manju compiled it as C++. While modern C allows variables to be declared in `for` loops like that, Turbo C++ would reject it when compiling as C. But it's still a C question.

Comment: @Joshua thank you I am not familiar with Turbo C++ at all.

Comment: Remove the `s` from `"%[^\n]s"`. The `s` will try to match a literal "s" in the input string. `%[..]` is a format specifier on its own. Then you should also limit the number of characters read, to prevent buffer overflow: `"%99[^\n]"`

Comment: @HAL9000 tnx for your help